# Back button always returns to start page in UWP Template10 App

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

We have a UWP app that uses Template10. Our landing page is JobPage. We use ViewModelNavigation in the form

`public void GoToCustomerPage() => NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.CustomerPage));`

If we navigate from the JobPage to the OrderPage and from the OrderPage to the CustomerPage then click the Back button we expect to return to the OrderPage but instead we return to the JobPage.

In the `CustomerPageViewModel` in `OnNavigatingFromAsync` the `NavigationService.NavigationState` is

```
1,3,2,17,UWP.Views.JobPage,0,0,19,UWP.Views.OrderPage,0,0,22,UWP.Views.CustomerPage,0,0
```

There is nothing in `OnNavigatingFromAsync`on the `CustomerPageViewModel` to redirect navigation to the JobPage. There is nothing in `OnNavigatedToAsync` on the `OrderPageViewModel` that redirects to the JobPage. `OrderPage.OnNavigatedToAsync` is not even hit.

Why is it when we click the Back button on the CustomerPage we go back to the JobPage and not the OrderPage?

**EDIT 1:** I have created a sample that demonstrates this issue [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiGVkyOWwr6JuGE1RmFnga4SZ1ax)

**EDIT 2:** I have referenced this issue on the Template 10 repo [Issue with the Navigation service](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/1441)

Comment: I tried to create a sample to test this issue but can not reproduce it, could you provide a minimal reproducible sample?

Comment: Thank you @BreezeLiu-MSFT. I have created a small sample app but am unable to reproduce the issue. I'll gradually build up the sample and if I am able to pinpoint where the issue arises I'll post that information back here.

Comment: Cauld you reproduce this issue later? Do you find where the problem is?

Comment: My apologies @Breeze Liu - MSFT for taking so long to respond; I had to focus on other matters. I have edited my question to include a reference to a sample app which demonstrates the issue.